# Detect if Foundation function has been ran

Tags: angularjs, zurb-foundation

I'm using Zurb Foundation framework on an Angular4 application. I use different elements of it (like dropdown menus, accordion, etc) on several components and each time I run the app I get a lot of warnings, like:

```
foundation.min.js:3 Tried to initialize responsive-toggle on an element that already has a Foundation plugin.
foundation.min.js:3 Tried to initialize accordion on an element that already has a Foundation plugin.
foundation.min.js:3 Tried to initialize dropdown-menu on an element that already has a Foundation plugin.
foundation.min.js:3 Tried to initialize responsive-toggle on an element that already has a Foundation plugin.
foundation.min.js:3 Tried to initialize sticky on an element that already has a Foundation plugin.
foundation.min.js:3 Tried to initialize accordion on an element that already has a Foundation plugin.
foundation.min.js:3 Tried to initialize dropdown-menu on an element that already has a Foundation plugin.
foundation.min.js:3 Tried to initialize responsive-toggle on an element that already has a Foundation plugin.
foundation.min.js:3 Tried to initialize sticky on an element that already has a Foundation plugin.
```

On each component that uses any of the Foundation elements that require Javscript, I run this:

```
ngOnInit() {
  // We initalize Foundation framework once the component has loaded
  $(document).foundation();
}
```

I tried running it only once on the main app component, but everything stops working.

I'd like to know if there's a way not to show this warnings, or make Foundation detect that it's already loaded.

Thanks!

Comment: I can't profess to being knowledgeable about angular, but usually those warnings occur when you are trying to init foundation plugins more than once. Double check you aren't calling `$(document).foundation();` more than once.

Comment: Hi! Yes, I know this happens because I run the function several more than once. I have to do it because there are components with Foundation elements that are loaded after the main app. So, when I call the function for the first time, they are not yet created and I have to call it again when they are initialized. If only I could disable these warning messages... Thanks for your comment!

Comment: If thats the case, use reinit rather than recalling foundation and use that inside your nginit. Example useage `Foundation.reInit($('[data-equalizer]'));`

Answer (score 0):

I had the answer right before my eyes:

Change `$(document).foundation();`

To `$("NEW_FOUNDATION_ELEMENT_SELECTOR").foundation();` on each component that uses a new Foundation control.

So, for example, in the Angular component that uses Foundation accordion the code in `ngOnInit` is:

```
ngOnInit() {
  [...]

  $(".accordion").foundation();
}
```

Doing this on all the components made the warnings disappear.